# Android UI: Fill the remaining screen with a max_height limit

Tags: android, android-layout

I wonder how to implement the following design in Android xml. The contents will have height wrap-contents with the most priority, and it could even fill the whole screen if there are enough contents. The image above it should fill up the remaining height - however it also has a limited max-height of 160dp. It seems if I use layout-weight or match-parent, the max-height param does not work anymore. Is there a way to do this in the xml? Or do I have to do it in the Java file programmatically? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

I'm using two textView just for test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#42A5F5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#EC407A"
        android:maxHeight="160dp"
        android:text="Image"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFEE58"
        android:text="Content"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

those are the important lines

```
android:maxHeight="160dp"
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```